# Sorting arrays in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js I have this array of arrays which I'm trying to sort by the timestamp:

```
var arr = [
        ["USER1", "2018-03-23T15:36", "S128290"],
        ["USER2", "2018-03-23T14:26", "S378256"],
        ["USER3", "2018-03-23T15:15", "S537524"]
    ];

arr.sort(function(a,b){
    var d1 = new Date(a[1]),
        d2 = new Date(b[1]);
    return (d1 > d2);
});
console.log(arr);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y9mz06b/)

It works in Firefox but it does nothing in nodejs, not even an error is shown.

Whitout using 3rd party packages, what is the proper way to sort this array in node.js?

Comment: I think you should use `d1.getTime() > d2.getTime()` instead of `d1 > d2`

Comment: `d1 - d2` not `d1 > d2`. By the way, `Array.prototype.sort()` is not a stable sort, so the implementation is allowed to re-order any indices that compare as equivalent

Comment: the array is **as is**. In the end, `return (d1 > d2)` will compare numbers anyway

Comment: @Azevedo if `d1 > d2` is false, the implementation will treat the values as equivalent. So no, it will not.

Comment: Are you certain your code is actually executing?  If you put a `console.log` up front does anything happen?  We may be chasing the wrong issue here.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you are correct. Now it is sorting. please post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**An alternative is to subtract the parsed string:**

**However, like [@georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) mentioned**

> in general, this is not how you sort ISO dates. Converting to a Date is just a waste of time and can follow to hard to find errors in some environments. Just compare them as strings - finally, that's what they are designed for!

So, this is the approach comparing strings:

```js
var arr = [
        ["USER1", "2018-03-23T15:36", "S128290"],
        ["USER2", "2018-03-23T14:26", "S378256"],
        ["USER3", "2018-03-23T15:15", "S537524"]
    ];

console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1])));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Correct. My mistake was doing `d1 < d2` instead of `d1 - d2`.

Comment: I understand that you just correcting the OP's mistake, but in general, this is not how you sort ISO dates. Converting to a Date is just a waste of time and can follow to hard to find errors in some environments. Just compare them as strings - finally, that's what they are designed for!